# Auto-scrolling problem in blogger website in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, autoscroll

I created a website https://www.saugatnpl.com.np using a blogger template. But I am facing a problem. I can't scroll to the end of the website on a mobile device. The website is working fine on the computer. But on mobile, it will automatically scroll up and I can't stay at the end of the page. I can't understand what's actually causing the problem. In case you would like to see the code, here it is [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/saugatsn/pen/BaJvYer). If I can't fix this, the site becomes useless so it'd be a great help if you could figure out the problem.

I think the problem lies in this segment but can't decide:

```
e.prototype.onThrottledResize = function () { 
  b.clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer),
  this.resizeTimer = b.setTimeout(
    this._handlers.onResize,
    this.settings.responsiveRefreshRate
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey for me it's work perfectly.
On Galaxy s20+5G

Comment: Now I have fixed it. Anyways thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my site. scrolling down then scrolls itself up after a threshold. You wrote that you solved the problem. Can you write how you did it?

Also, I found a hint for the  scripts inside, I think it's relevant.

```
draggable:true,easing:'linear',edgeFriction:0.35,fade:false,focusOnSelect:false,infinite:true,initialSlide:0,lazyLoad:'ondemand',mobileFirst:false,pauseOnHover:true,pauseOnFocus:true,pauseOnDotsHover:false,respondTo:'window',responsive:null,rows:1,rtl:false,slide:'',slidesPerRow:1,slidesToShow:1,slidesToScroll:1,speed:500,swipe:true,swipeToSlide:false,touchMove:true,touchThreshold:5,useCSS:true,
```

although I changed some functions here, java implementation is limited

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32336992)